# Understanding the logic flow of decorators

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to understand decorators, so thought I'd start with the simplest cases, checking/modifying the output of a function:

Example 1:

```
def checkIsFriend(func):
    def wrapper(arg):
        friends = ['alan', 'brian', 'carol']
        ret = arg # function not called
        if ret in friends:
            return 'hello {}, good to see you!'.format(ret)
        else:
            return 'Sorry {}, don\'t know you...'.format(ret)
    return wrapper

@checkIsFriend
def greet(name):
    return 'hi {}, good to see you!'.format(name)

print greet('alan')
print greet('simon')

# output:
# hello alan, good to see you!
# Sorry simon, don't know you...
```

Example 2:

```
def reject_vowels(func):
    def wrapper():
        reject = 'aieou'
        new_str = []
        ret = func() # need to call the function
        for char in ret:
            if char in reject:
                continue
            new_str.append(char)
        return ''.join(new_str)
    return wrapper

@reject_vowels
def make_string():
    return 'hello world, how are you?'

print make_string()

# output:
# hll wrld, hw r y?
```

What is confusing me is that in example 1, the argument to the decorated function (arg) is not called.

In example 2, I need to call the function.

Can anyone explain the flow for these examples, please?

Comment: The idea is that `func` will be replaced by `wrapper`. `arg` needs to be passed to `func`, not called (`ret = arg()`) itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decorators that you posted do different things.

- In example 1, the decorated function `greet` is replaced by a new function with one argument `arg` that does not use `greet` for anything. In fact, if you change the body of `greet` for anything else, the result will be exactly the same. This new function does some operation with the argument it receives and returns the result; the operation it does is similar to the decorated function `greet`, but it is not related to it anyhow, and would the same no matter what function you are decorating.
- In example 2, the decorated function `make_string` is replaced by a new function with no parameters that calls `make_string`, does something with its output and returns the result. In this case, if you had decorated a different function the result would be different, because the new function is actually using the function received by the decorator.

Decorators do not require you to actually use the decorated function (like having a parameter in a function does not require you to actually use it). They will just replace the decorated thing with their returned value, which can be *anything*. Usually it is something that you can call and that does something *related* to the decorated function, because otherwise it generally isn't very useful (for example, in example 1 you could just have a regular function that does what `wrapper` does), but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that `wrapper` will *replace* the decorated function; decorator syntax is short for function application.

```
@checkIsFriend
def greet(name):
    ...
```

is just short for

```
def greet(name):
    ...

greet = checkIsFriend(greet)
```

Knowing that, `checkIsFriend` should be defined as

```
def checkIsFriend(func):
    def wrapper(arg):
        friends = ['alan', 'brian', 'carol']
        if arg in friends:
            return func(arg)
        else:
            return 'Sorry {}, don\'t know you...'.format(arg)
    return wrapper
```

Here, `func` may be your `greet` function, or any other function. Inside the wrapper, we don't know anything about `func` except that it takes a single argument and will return a value. The wrapper is a new function that takes the same argument as `func`, and indeed just examines the value of that argument to decide whether to simply call `func` or to return a different string instead.

It might make a little more sense if we define a helper replacement for `func`:

```
def checkIsFriend(func):
    friends = ['alan', 'brian', 'carol']

    def donotgreet(arg):
        return "Sorry {}, don't know you...".format(arg)

    def wrapper(arg):
        if arg in friends:
            f = func
        else:
            f = donotgreet
        return f(arg)

    return wrapper
```

All the wrapper does is decide whether to pass its argument to and call either the original function or the decorator-defined default function, depending on what argument it receives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, chepner. How is example 1 able to work though, when the function has not been called???

Comment: Because you reimplented the function in the body of `wrapper`. Try decorating a function completely different from `greet`, and it's still going to *behave* like `greet`. You not only didn't call `func`, but you ignored it altogether.